# OpenXML- Copy Formula is not working after generating excel file

Tags: c#, openxml

I have created one application using openXML features to export excel file. Initially I tried to fill excel cell by cell but, I faced performance issue because of bulk data. Then I copied datatable content into Excel table.
Now I am able to generate bulk data.
But after generating excel file I am **not able apply copy formula.**

Comment: please show some code

Comment: SLDocument sl = new SLDocument();
int iStartRowIndex = 8;
int iStartColumnIndex = 1;

Comment: sl.ImportDataTable(iStartRowIndex, iStartColumnIndex, table, true); 
int iEndRowIndex = iStartRowIndex + table.Rows.Count + 1 - 1;
int iEndColumnIndex = iStartColumnIndex + table.Columns.Count - 1;

Comment: SLTable tabledesign = sl.CreateTable(iStartRowIndex, iStartColumnIndex, iEndRowIndex, iEndColumnIndex);
tabledesign.HasAutoFilter = false;
tabledesign.SetTableStyle(SLTableStyleTypeValues.Light9);
sl.InsertTable(tabledesign);

Comment: Please refer the above code and help me to continue...